# laravel authentication with mongo db

Tags: php, laravel, mongodb

```
    `<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers\Backend\V2\Member\Register;

use App\Http\Controllers\Controller;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;
use App\Models\Mongodb\User; 
use Validator;
use App\Exceptions\ApplicationError;
use Log;

class Store extends Controller
{
    public function __invoke(Request $request)
    {
        try
        {
            $data = $request->all();

            $formValidation = Validator::make($data, [
                'name'      => 'required|min:1|max:20',
                'surname'   => 'required|min:1|max:20',
                'email'     => 'required|email',
                'phone'     => 'required|min:1|max:20',
                'password'  => 'required|min:1|max:16|confirmed',
            ]);
            
            if ($formValidation->fails()) {
                $errorMessage = is_array($formValidation->errors()->getMessages()) ?
                    current(data_get($formValidation->errors()->getMessages(), '*.0')) :
                    $formValidation->errors()->first();

                return response()->json(["status" => "error", "message" => __('lang-account.'.$errorMessage)], 200);
            }`

            unset($data["password_confirmation"]);

  
            $existingUser = User::where('email', $data['email'])->first();
            if ($existingUser) {
                throw new ApplicationError(__('lang-account.app.avaliable_email'));
            }

            // Parolayı hashle
            $data['password'] = bcrypt($data['password']);

           
            User::create($data);

            
            $request->session()->regenerate();

            return response()->json(['status' => 'success']);
        }
        catch (ApplicationError $e)
        {
            $errors = $e->getMessageArr();

            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => collect($errors)->first()], 200);
        }
        catch(Exception $e)
        {
            Log::error(__CLASS__." ".$e->getMessage()." ".$e->getFile()." ".$e->getLine());
            $errors[] = __('lang-account.app.unkown_error').' '.__('lang-account.app.unkown_error');
            return response()->json(['status' => 'error', 'message' => $errors]);
        }
    }
}
```

`

While performing Laravel authentication processes, I cannot see the user data in my MongoDB collection after the user registration. Can you identify the error in this code? Because I'm not sure if I'm going in the right direction without creating a session. I had previously implemented it based on the SQL structure and then changed it.

Answer (score 0):

Need to change the connection for the User model to **mongodb**

```
class User {

    protected $connection= 'mongodb_connection';

    protected $table = 'users';

}
```

your `database.php` config

```
return array(
    'connections' => array(
        'mysql' => array(
            'driver' => 'mysql',
            'host' => 'localhost',
            'database' => 'db',
            'username' => 'root',
            'password' => 'secret'
            'charset' => 'utf8',
            'collation' => 'utf8_unicode_ci',
            'prefix' => '',
        ),

        'mongodb_connection' => array(
            'driver' => 'mongodb',
            'dsn' => env('DB_URI', 'mongodb+srv://username:password@<atlas-cluster-uri>/myappdb?retryWrites=true&w=majority'),
            'database' => 'myappdb',
        ),
    ),
```

Comment: They are all set, I checked all the ports but it still doesn't work.

Comment: Is the connection to the database working correctly? Does the controller work without errors? It often happens that incorrect data for accessing the database is simply specified in the `.env` file. For example, you test on a dev stand, but you record everything on a prod.

Comment: Database connection works fine but controller gives error

Comment: can you send the error?

Comment: You were right, I missed a detail in the database connection. It works now. thank you so much

Comment: Glad to hear it, you're welcome.